# Installing vsftpd

Tags: ssl, vsftpd

I installed vsftpd with apt install on ubuntu 22.04. Install seems okay but it fails to start because of an Invalid Argument.
I found out the snakeoil files are missing.
Is there a way to recreate them without reinstalling SSL and the certificates?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details: Did you install the Ubuntu package `vsftp` or did you install it in some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer on GitHub and it worked for me generating the snake oil files I needed to get vsftpd.service to start. From Terminal enter the following:

sudo apt-get install ssl-cert
sudo make-ssl-cert generate-default-snakeoil
sudo usermod --append --groups ssl-cert [user]
ls -l /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key